# Django views.py invalid syntax

Tags: python, django, sendgrid

I want to send email to multiple recipients in Django, using SendGrid.

In my **views.py** file I have this and it works:

```
data = {
    "personalizations": [
        {
            "to": [
                {"email": "address@example.com"},
                {"email": "address2@example.com"},
            ],
            "subject": "New message
        }
    ],
    "from": {
        "email": email
    },
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "text/plain",
            "value": message
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want to add addresses from loop. So, I use:

```
"to": [
    for address in addresses:
        {"email": address},
],
```

and I get the following error:

```
    for address in addresses:
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `list comprehension`

```
"to": [{"email": address} for address in addresses]
```

Comment: Thanks! How I can add the comma after `{"email": address}`?

Comment: It will be comma separated like `[{'email':'email1'}, {'email': 'email2'},..]` if `addresses` is list of emails

Comment: `addresses` in my case is `Model.objects.all()`. I don't know where I'm wrong.