# Loop value is not JSON serializable in Django

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, sendgrid

In Django, I have this model:

```
class CO(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

in my view, I try to [send email to multiple recipients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44260033/django-views-py-invalid-syntax) using:

```
addresses = CO.objects.all()

data = {
    "personalizations": [
        {
            "to": [{"email": address} for address in addresses],
        }
    ],
...
```

but I get the following error:
`<CO: address@gmail.com> is not JSON serializable`

I tried with `list(PR.objects.values())` and `for address in json.dumps(addresses)` but I receive bad request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44260033/django-views-py-invalid-syntax...!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django views.py invalid syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44260033/django-views-py-invalid-syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the email from address object.

```
[{"email": address.email} for address in addresses]
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Is any way to add comma after `{"email": address.email}`? I get bad request from SendGrid without it.

Comment: Where do you want the comma?

Comment: Please, see my other question.

Comment: @Yidipen Actually this will put the comma after `[{"email": ??}, {"email": ??}] `

Comment: The bad request is actually because you have an *extra* comma, after the close square bracket.